# I am trying to force three fields to be populated if the value of one field is a specific item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list, validation-list-items

I can validate one field with no problem but everything I do to validate multiple fails.  I need to add another two though so FIELD3 and FIELD4.

```
=IF([FIELD1]="Specific Value",IF([FIELD2]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF([FIELD1]="Specific Value",AND([FIELD2]<>"", AND([FIELD3]<>"",[FIELD4]<>"")),TRUE)
```

Comment: This DID NOT work.  This logic forces values into those three fields regardless of what value is in FIELD1 - I need it to be the SPecific Value ONLLY.  

Also some minor syntax issues with bracket on Field4 but otherwise worked great =IF([FIELD1]="Specific Value",AND([FIELD2]<>"", AND([FIELD3]<>"",AND([FIELD4]<>"")),TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sample formula:

```
=IF([FIELD1]="Specific Value",AND(IF([FIELD2]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF([FIELD3]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),IF([FIELD4]<>"",TRUE,FALSE)),TRUE)
```

It forces values in all three field all at once.